# Can I do a wildcard with 'responds-to format' in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, format, respond-to

Consider the following code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js  { render :layout => false }
  format.xml { head :ok }
end
```

Now I know you can specify a whole bunch of formats, but is there a way to specify **all other formats** (in this case other than .jx and .xml) to save me from having to specify every specific format explicitly?

I guess I kind of want an "if-else" type condition.  Is this possible with `respond_to do |format|`?

Comment: I would call this post a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671111/methods-for-limiting-the-rails-render-format-to-html/2470191#2470191 (because the required answer is in there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good answer for you here: [Can Ruby on Rails's respond_to return a line when the format is not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3587426/657003)  although they posed their question differently.
hth
Perry